# Android Browser and Drawing on a HTML5 Canvas ... Has anyone ever done this?

Tags: android, html, tablet, html5-canvas

Has anyone ever been able to draw on a html5 canvas using an Android tablet?

I can't see why drawing on a canvas is not possible?

Could it be the browser or the actually touch screen?

Can anyone with a tablet try to scribble on the HTML5 Canvas Demo available on this page please?

http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/

Comment: What do you mean by using an Android tablet? The browser in my phone is displaying a canvas with some graphics on, but the WebView on my phone is not displaying the graphics. Don't know if that is related or not.

Comment: Android's default browser is pretty aweful at any canvas output. The new Chrome for Android is much better but is still sluggish compared to iOS Safari. The latest version of Maxthon is also pretty good. Android browsers are lagging behind in canvas performance compared to iOS unfortunately - I love my Galaxy though :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes i did canvas with android browsers but i've got performance problems. Works fine with iPads.

I'm just doing a smoothing with strokes for rendering the handwriting in the input method.

test here : http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its depends on what browser you use. I use Opera Mobile as my browser and the html5 canvas works great there, havent tried the other browsers though

Comment: Can you actually draw on the canvas on this page with your tablet?

Comment: Ohh, did you mean draw as in paint. I though you meant just drawing. When I read your question now its obvious what you mean :) 

It could be that the canvas dont handle the touch movement as mousemovent or the browser you use dont support mousemovment at al yet. (Opera mobile supports atleast mouseclick (eg tuchclick) but I dont know if it handles movement